# Tuning mdadm RAID 5 performance?

Tags: performance, software-raid, ssd

I have a system with dual [Intel E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/83352/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v3-15M-Cache-2_40-GHz), 64 GB ram, an [LSI 3008 HBA](http://www.supermicro.com/products/accessories/addon/AOC-S3008L-L8e.cfm), 8x [1.6 TB Intel S3510 SSDs](http://ark.intel.com/products/86192/Intel-SSD-DC-S3510-Series-1_6TB-2_5in-SATA-6Gbs-16nm-MLC).  I've been playing benchmarking it in different configurations using fio and I've gotten some interesting results.  Benchmarking each raw disk individually, I'm seeing ~450 MB/s random writes per device.  In a RAID0 (stripe without parity) I'm seeing **~3500 MB/s** random writes - basically 450 * 8 disks.

However, when I tried RAID 5, performance completely tanked.  I realize raid5 should be significantly worse than raid0, but RAID5 performance using the same test was about **50 MB/s**.  I've used RAID 5 before and while the performance has never been great, I've never seen a 99% penalty for it.  The fio test I'm running has 600 threads writing random data in 512k blocks.  The filesystem on the device is xfs for all these tests.

Setting `/sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size` to 32768 (the maximum possible value) increased the overall throughput to **~130 MB/s**, leading me to assume that the problem is the lack of a writeback cache like those found in hardware RAID controllers.  But I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to improve the mdadm raid 5 performance.  Any idea what could be causing this, or how to improve raid 5 performance?

Interestingly, I also tried a 16-disk RAID-10 (same disks plus a second LSI HBA) and the performance was ~2400 MB/s - a 33% decrease from RAID 0.  Given how RAID10 works, I would have expected the performance to be nearly identical to RAID 0.

For anyone interested, here's the fio config file:

```
[global]
rw=randwrite
direct=1
numjobs=600
group_reporting
bs=512k
runtime=120
ramp_time=5
size=10G


[raid]
new_group
directory=/raid/
```